# Right way to continuously update color of Tkinter Canvas item

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to figure out how to change a rectangle's color continuously, with a second between each change. Right now I have this simple function which makes a window with a square above a button, that changes the color of the square after every button click:

```
def junk():
    def random_color():
        red = int(random.random()*256)
        green = int(random.random()*256)
        blue = int(random.random()*256)
        return '#' + ('{:0>#02X}'*3).format(red,green,blue)

    def change_color():
        c.itemconfig(r, fill=random_color())

    x = Tkinter.Tk()
    c = Tkinter.Canvas(master=x)
    c['width'] = 400; c['height'] = 400
    r = c.create_rectangle(0,0,400,400)
    b = Tkinter.Button(master=x, command=change_color)
    b['text'] = 'change color'
    c.pack(); b.pack(); x.mainloop()
```

What I want is to be able to click once, and then have the colors change automatically. I know I want to use a `CheckButton` instead of a `Button` for this, so that one click will start the loop, and and the next click will stop it.

Also, this is not how I am structuring my "real" code, this is how I am testing from the IDLE shell. Defining the helper functions inside the `junk` function makes it easy to get at all the relevant code at once, without having the bloat of a full class. So please don't give me comments on style, this is quick and dirty on purpose.

**TL;DR** I'm not sure how to get a continuous loop running to change the color, while being able to start and stop the loop with a button click.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Before I show my solution, I want to correct a mistaken statement I made above: I don't to use a `Checkbutton` to make this work. I can make a normal button into a toggle button by changing the 'relief' option of the button. Here is my solution:

```
def junk():
    def color_poll():
        global alarm
        c.itemconfig(r, fill=random_color())
        if keep_going:
            alarm = c.after(1000, color_poll)

    def change_color():
        global keep_going, alarm
        if not keep_going:
            keep_going = True
            b['text']='STOP';b['fg']='red';b['relief']=Tkinter.SUNKEN
            color_poll()
        else:
            keep_going = False; c.after_cancel(alarm); alarm = None
            b['text']='GO';b['fg']='green';b['relief']=Tkinter.RAISED

    x = Tkinter.Tk()
    c = Tkinter.Canvas(master=x)
    c['width'] = 400; c['height'] = 400
    r = c.create_rectangle(0,0,400,400)
    global keep_going, alarm
    keep_going = False; alarm = None
    b = Tkinter.Button(master=x, command=change_color)
    b['text'] = 'GO';b['fg']='green';b['font']='Arial 16';b['relief']=Tkinter.RAISED
    c.pack(); b.pack(); x.mainloop()
```

I'm using the same `random_color` function, but I moved it out because it out of the `junk` function because it didn't need to be there.